# Get data from 2 successives activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to get datas from a third activity to my first activity.

It looks like that :

Activity A (my Form) , I click on a button to generate a test  -> Activity B ( choose a device to connect ) -> Activity C (generate datas) -> Activity A ( get the datas from Activity C)

I want to generate many tests on the same session , so I want to keep my datas.

Comment: You can pass data when you start activities with intents. If you want to manage data across your app, I would recommend looking into a MVC architecture and hold your data in a model separate from the activities.

Comment: Yes I can pass the data , but i have many tests (the number is not fixed) , and i have also datas like pictures in Base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

For your example, if you have ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC, you could return to ActivityA from ActivityC with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Activity.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtras(<DATA_NAME>, <DATA_VALUE>);
```

You activity will be launched with this new intent containing your data. Activity B and C will be finished.

Comment: I will use your solution , with putExtra on my activity A and B , because I have to save the datas input.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in the form of string or integer then you can use SharedPrefrences to store them . The data will remain stored until application is uninstalled or application data is cleared .You can store and get this data from any activity of your application  . An Example is [here](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/) if you need

Comment: I think about it , but it's not my solution , I can send it with some intent , but I ask if it exists a better solution.